How to remove Tab Item Shadow on pressed state on Android on Expo 52?
I’m working with an Expo 52 app and using expo-router to implement a bottom tab navigation using the Tabs component. By default, the tab items have a shadow effect, especially when pressed. This is particularly noticeable on Android.
I want to remove the shadow effect from the tab items when they are pressed or in their default state. I’m using the tabBarStyle and screenOptions to customize the appearance of the tabs, but I haven’t been able to remove the shadow on Android.
Can anyone help me remove the tab item shadow effect on Android for both the default and pressed states?
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import FeatherIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather'; // Example import, replace with your actual icon component
import Colors from './path-to-colors'; // Your color definitions
import { iconSize, TABBAR_HEIGHT } from './path-to-your-config'; // Your size and height constants

export default function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={({}) => ({
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000',
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        lazy: true,
        tabBarStyle: {
          position: 'absolute',
          height: TABBAR_HEIGHT - 25,
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingVertical: 0,
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0, // Removes shadow on Android
          shadowOpacity: 0, // Removes shadow on iOS
          shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
          },
        },
        tabBarIconStyle: {
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        animation: 'fade',
      })}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="home"
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <FeatherIcon
              name="home"
              color={focused ? Colors.redKure : Colors.c7d7d7d}
              width={iconSize.m + 3}
              height={iconSize.m + 3}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
/* The rest of the code.. */

!Screenshot for the issue]1
